# EntityQuery for taxonomy term of specific bundle

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, database

I would like to build a query for all taxonomy terms of a specific bundle.

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition('type','mail_template')
  ->execute();
```

This returns an error `'type' not found`.

How do I query taxonomy terms of a specific bundle (specific vocabulary)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Drupal 8 you should use the `entityTypeManager` for this task.

This code will load all terms from the `mail_template` vocabulary.

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadByProperties([
  'vid' => 'mail_template',
]);
```

Answer (score 8):

This works :

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition('vid','mail_template')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: Note that since Drupal 9.2, entityQuery use requires an additional call to the `->accessCheck()` method to explicitly decide whether your query checks access to the queried entities or not. https://www.drupal.org/node/3201242

Answer (score 3):

```
            $termData = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
            ->loadByProperties(['vid' => 'vocabulary_name']);
```

Always works :D

If you also have the name it is

`->loadByProperties(['name' => $term, 'vid' => 'selected_keyword']);`

If you need the id from what is returned

`// returns an array with the tid as the key so
                foreach ($termData as $key => $value){
                    $termId = $key;
                // I need the first and only
                    break;
                }`